# PubNub GCM Push Nortification is not showing in Nortification bar

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, chat, pubnub

I'm developing a Android IM Chat app using PubNub and Backendless. I'm currently working on sending a Push Notification to user when they get a new chat message. I successfully integrated PubNub and GCM. So, I can send notification to the device using those two services. I followed this tutorial to get this done.

https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2015-06-24-sending-receiving-android-push-notifications-with-gcm-google-cloud-messaging/

But even though notification message is sending, it's not showing in the notification bar of the mobile phone as a push notification. Message come to the device with the tone. But no message is showing as notification bar. Can anyone please help me with the issue. Here is my code so far

This is my AndroidManifest file

```
<permission android:name="your.package.name.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="your.package.name.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

<!--<receiver
    android:name="your.package.name.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
        <category android:name="your.package.name" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>-->
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="your.package.name" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
<!-- [START gcm_listener] -->
<service
    android:name="your.package.name.MyGcmListenerService"
    android:exported="false" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
<!-- [END gcm_listener] -->
<!-- [START instanceId_listener] -->
<service
    android:name="your.package.name.MyInstanceIDListenerService"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
<!-- [END instanceId_listener] -->
<service
    android:name="your.package.name.RegistrationIntentService"
    android:exported="false">
</service>

</application>
```

This is my MainActivity Class ( Some Parts of the class)

[ Send Notification method ]

```
public void sendNotification() {
    PnGcmMessage gcmMessage = new PnGcmMessage();
    JSONObject jso = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jso.put("GCMSays", "hi");
    } catch (JSONException e) { }
    gcmMessage.setData(jso);



    PnMessage message = new PnMessage(
            pubnub,
            "GCMPush",
            callback,
            gcmMessage);
    try {
        message.publish();
    } catch (PubnubException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is GCMListenerService class

```
ublic class MyGcmListenerService extends GcmListenerService {

private static final String TAG = "MyGcmListenerService";
// [START receive_message]
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
    String message = data.getString("message");
    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + from);
    Log.d(TAG, "Message: " + message);

    if (from.startsWith("/topics/")) {
        // message received from some topic.
    } else {
        // normal downstream message.
    }
}
/**
 * Create and show a simple notification containing the received GCM message.
 *
 * @param message GCM message received.
 */
private void sendNotification(String message) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            //.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_ic_notification)
            .setContentTitle("GCM Message")
            .setContentText(message)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message));

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Can anyone please tell what is the wrong with this implementation. I can give you more code if you want.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I found the error I have been made when I was defining the sendNortification method. I have commented out the .`setSmallIcon` property in `NotificationCompact` which is a required notification content.

Thanks